# Font discrepancies in various browsers, is there a solution to this?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm working on a project where the height of the content container is limited, and on a few select browsers (mostly Chrome on Android) the text seems to be breaking in different places, even though almost all font properties seem identical, so far I've checked:

- Width of the container element
- font-size
- line-height
- font-family
- letter-spacing

All of which are identical, both in their given and computed values.

This wouldn't usually be a massive problem, but because of the content container height constraint, these discrepancies are causing me a massive headache.

I've managed to replicate the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79j57L8L/1/) with the following code:

HTML

```
<p>We are not able to sleep or We cannot sleep.</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

The text in this example renders on one line in the majority of browsers, however in some the last word "sleep." appears on a new line.

You can see screenshots of this example in a number of different browsers at:

http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/cf75bb4fa9a22db2e660a0073698be86b55becb6

Is there something I'm missing here? Is there any way to ensure the text will render in the same way accross a number of devices and browers?

Comment: I'd suggest using `em` and even defining the width in `em` and see if that helps you. But yeah, browsers interpret fonts differently...

Comment: I doubt using em will fix this, but I'll give it a shot ... it is frustrating that browsers interpret the text that differently considering they have the same font-family, size etc. it's not like times new roman isn't a standard font either /rantover

Comment: `em` unit won't make a difference; also what if the user resizes the font-size in their browser settings (no zoom)? Same issue. You're missing nothing, simply differences between browsers (and OS) in rendering text are unavoidable.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, not sure how I'm going to get around this as the height constraint is something I can't get around ... a couple of lines breaking in the wrong places can push content over the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of font rendering vary by browser and platform, and they cannot be controlled in CSS. Besides, different computers may have (slightly) different fonts under the same name, or e.g. lack Times New Roman entirely (most smartphones lack it, for example).

As a workaround, if specific line division is crucial, consider writing the text as preformatted (i.e. dividing it into lines in HTML source the way it should appear in display) and using `white-space: pre`. The drawback is that some lines might hit or even cross the right edge of the area reserved for the element. But if you do not set a background or border, this will be barely noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the only solution here is using an image using width="XXX" or tell the client that is completely impossible to make a web identically on every browsers unless you use disgraceful methods just like using an image instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem in my browser by replacing the max-width with min-width see this http://jsfiddle.net/79j57L8L/4/

```
p {
font-family:"Times New Roman", serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-style: italic;
min-width: 200px;
}
```